# How to set Neumann BC for coupled transport problem in weak form?

Tags: finite-element, pde, boundary-conditions, weak-solution

Consider

$$\begin{aligned}
    \partial_t v + b\cdot \nabla \phi &=0 \\
    \partial_t \phi + b\cdot \nabla v &= 0
\end{aligned}$$

for $v:(x,y)\mapsto \mathbb{R}$, unknown and time-dependent ($\phi$ similary), and $b\in \mathbb{R}^2$ given, and divergence-free. A weak form in $H^1$ is

$$\begin{aligned}
    \int \partial_t v w -\int \phi b\cdot \nabla w  &= -\int_\Gamma \phi_\Gamma w b \cdot e_n  \quad \forall w\in H^1\\
    \int \partial_t \phi \psi -\int v b\cdot \nabla \psi  &= -\int_\Gamma V_\Gamma \psi b\cdot e_n \quad \forall \psi\in H^1    
\end{aligned}$$

where $\Gamma$ denotes the domain boundary, and $\int$ denotes a (non-parametrized) integral over the domain.

Am I right to assume, that a Neumann boundary condition, like ($n$ denoting the outward-pointing, unit normal vector)

$$n\cdot \nabla v \equiv g$$

can not be enforced in a "natural" way, i.e. by manipulating the above weak form?

If so, does this imply that the BC has to be enforced by posing the problem on an adapted function space, which includes the condition in its definition, e.g.

$$H^1_\nabla \equiv  \left \{ u\in H^1 : (n\cdot \nabla u)|_{(x,y)\in \Gamma} \equiv g \right \} ?$$

---

Background info: I would like to solve the problem using FEM.

Comment: I don't think you need to rewrite $\int w b\cdot\nabla \phi$ using the divergence theorem, and similarly for the other one, it doesn't gain you anything as far as I can tell. As far as the BC goes I think you would need to prescribe it explicitly in some manner.

Comment: The application of the divergence theorem does not allow the enforcement of the stated BC. It does, however, allow for less regular solutions, or more concretely: solutions that are only weakly differentiable in the spatial coordinates. Please correct me, if my reasoning is incorrect.

Comment: With "prescribe it explicitly in some manner", do you mean the way I have proposed in the question, i.e. to include the condition in the function space definition?

Comment: The divergence theorem here really doesn't seem to do anything except move the derivative to the test function. If you are considering Petrov-Galerkin then it may make sense, however if the solution and test functions space is the same there's no difference except you now also have to deal with a boundary term. As far as prescribe it explicitly, I mean something like that yes. Once you discretise you will have to enforce this as an additional linear constraint acting on your node values.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: Maybe I should mention that the space $H^1$ cannot formally contain the constraint you want because the order of the boundary derivative is too high (it's termed a natural condition as opposed to a stable one). Gazolla's book has a bit on this. Not to worry though - that shouldn't be an issue in practice when you have discretised ghe problem.

Comment: $H^1$-functions have square integrable first derivatives/gradients. My constraint is a directional derivative of first order. Why is this not allowed?

Comment: Because it's on the boundary, where you can have "derivatives" only up to order $\frac{1}{2}$. Read Gazolla's book - he also has a freely available version. It's not allowed in the sense of a strong derivative, instead one uses some tricks to deal with it. But that's a purely theoretical consideration, you should have no issues whatsoever once you discretize.

Comment: Please, if possible, provide the full book title. I can not find anything related to mathematics from "Gazolla".

Comment: Polyharmonic boundary value problems - it is available here: https://www.math.ovgu.de/grunau.html

Comment: Thank you very much!